# Html.fromHtml(text) not working

Tags: android, html, custom-adapter

this works in onCreate of the activity

```
String htmlstring="<p><em><strong>hello world</strong></em></p>";

    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

But when i used the same from a server in a listview its not working

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.quest = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.question_data);

            holder.quest.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlstring));
```

What is wrong! how can  i achieve this?

Comment: hai, thats an arraylist that i access in the getView() method, any way thanks i sorted out the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was not the custom adapter that was causing the problem, i was parsing the html data from the server which displayed the
< as "<" and  > comes as "&gt" so i replaced these two values

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(htmlstring.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">"));
 textview.setText(sp);
```

And it worked fine..hope somebody gets help with this answer